# bash_profile function to git grep and replace

Tags: bash, git, xargs

I wanted to create a function in my ~/.bash_profile that would git grep and list the files that contains a string and then replace all occurrences of that string with another

`function git-replace() { eval git grep -l ${1} | xargs sed -i '' -e 's/${1}/${2}/g' ; }`

However, if I run the function `git-replace "Type1" "Type2"` , nothing happens. What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's 2 issues:

- don't use the *evil* `eval`
- if you want to expand a variable, don't use single quotes but double quotes, so:

```sh
git-replace() {
    git grep -l "$1" | xargs sed -i '' -e "s/$1/$2/g"
}
```

And no need the `function` statement in modern shell.

Learn how to quote properly in shell, it's very important :

> "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
>   http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
>   http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
>   http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words